# IM-Config head / tail error

Tags: ibus, input-language, input-method, inputrc

Trying to change my Input Method with `im-config` outputs this after I select and save what I want to use.

```
head: error reading ‘adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702’: Is a directory
tail: error reading ‘adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702’: Is a directory
E: Configuration in adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702 is manually managed. Doing nothing.
```

Why is im-config trying to read a directory that's in my home folder? Because this is preventing me from being able to change my input method from `default` to `ibus`

How can I tell im-config to change my input method without it trying to read a directory in my home folder? It shouldn't be doing that, it's suppose to change my `im-config` I've selected.

to produce this error all I'm doing is;

```
 sudo im-config
[sudo] password for user:

** (zenity:20841): WARNING **: Can't load fallback CSS resource: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-fallback.css' does not exist

** (zenity:20841): WARNING **: Can't load fallback CSS resource: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-fallback.css' does not exist

(zenity:20841): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/user/.config/ibus/bus is not root!

** (zenity:20852): WARNING **: Can't load fallback CSS resource: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-fallback.css' does not exist

** (zenity:20852): WARNING **: Can't load fallback CSS resource: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-fallback.css' does not exist
head: error reading ‘adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702’: Is a directory
tail: error reading ‘adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702’: Is a directory
E: Configuration in adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702 is manually managed. Doing nothing.
```

I need to be able to change my input method so that iBus will work correctly with other language inputs like iBus-Anthy as well as some applications that require an input method it can actually read, because it doesn't work on default as it's currently selected on.

I've also checked that running `im-config` as normal user level still gets the same error as when trying to run as root.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 14.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found my solution I eventually came to, before that typing `im-config` without any options into `gnome-terminal` would produce these errors errors;

```
head: error reading ‘adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702’: Is a directory
tail: error reading ‘adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702’: Is a directory
E: Configuration in adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702 is manually managed. Doing nothing.
```

in the home directory if there's no `.xinputrc` file it then looks at trying to write to a directory after you've made your selections with `zenity` GUI interface instead of creating a new file and writing to `.xinputrc`

### Solution:

In terminal instead of just typing `im-config` alone do;

```
$ im-config -c
```

and you will instead be configuring through terminal screen to complete the setup properly and will properly create and write `.xinputrc` file into your home directory without doing the error of trying to write to a directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

im-config is not supposed to be run as root.

Try to run this command:

```
sudo rm ~/.xinputrc
```

and then run im-config without sudo again.

Comment: well that was kinda obvious… but anyway -->>  `rm: cannot remove ‘/home/user/.xinputrc’: No such file or directory` and same thing again with the said error like I mentioned before.

Comment: @user94959: I can't see anything obvious with your issue. ;) im-config is supposed to apply `head()` and `tail()` to a file represented by the `$IM_CONFIG_XINPUTRC` variable, whose value should be either "/etc/X11/xinit/xinputrc" or "$HOME/.xinputrc". From the output you showed us it looks like `$IM_CONFIG_XINPUTRC` is assigned the value "adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702", which is a complete mystery to me. What happens if you open the _Language Support_ GUI and set the desired input method from there? (Actually that's the easiest way. Normally you shouldn't need to call im-config directly.)

Comment: The issue here is it's trying to write to a directory which shouldn't be doing that when it's suppose to create and write to the config file `.xinputrc` in the home directory instead it's looking at a directory to write to. I eventually found my solution, from Terminal I went to see what happened when I did `im-config -c` instead of the GUI interface with Zenity and I was able to set the desired input method without the said errors with it trying to write to a directory, and it properly created and written `.xinputrc` file like it's suppose to.

Comment: @user94959: Ok, great that you solved it. Really strange that the use of zenity can cause such confusion, though. (Btw, it means that using _Language Support_, as I suggested, most likely had worked fine too.)